# How to show list survey in ModalDialog

Tags: modal-dialog, survey

I need to show my list Survey in ModalDialog ,with all the benefits of Survey:Rrespond, statictis, chart.

I tried `overview.aspx` but no chance:

```
url= "http://srvdev:2222/listeInstances/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/Lists/enquete formation/overview.aspx?"

function openJSdialogsurvey(url) {

    SP.SOD.execute("sp.ui.dialog.js", "SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog", {
        url: url +"IsDlg=1",
        title: "", allowMaximize: true, showClose: true,
    });

}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried this code and it works perfectly for me. I have kept this code in Content Editor WebPart.

```
<a href="JavaScript:var options=SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
options.url='http://srvdev:2222/listeInstances/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/Lists/enquete formation/overview.aspx';
options.height = 400;
void(SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options))"
> Click here! </a>
```

Thanks